# trying to change values with firepropertychange,propertychangesupport

Tags: java, inotifypropertychanged

i writing java program using propertychangesupport,propertychange and fireproperty change, now its working but not at all case, when i i change the value and printed it its working, but when i tried to do a while loop on the spesipic class that listen to change it just wond get out the loop when i put it in the while condition,

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        CLI cli = new CLI(System.in,System.out);
        Server server = new Server(34567);
        cli.addPropertyChangeListener(server);
        new Thread(cli).start();
}
```

}

public class CLI implements Runnable{

```
private Scanner scanner;
private String userInput;
private PropertyChangeSupport pcs;
private Boolean serverIsRunning;

public CLI(InputStream in, OutputStream out){
    this.scanner = new Scanner(in);
    pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    serverIsRunning = false;
}


@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("pls enter your command:");
        userInput = scanner.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();
        switch (userInput) {
            case "START":
                if (!serverIsRunning)   {
                    pcs.firePropertyChange(userInput, null, "START");
                    new Thread(new Server(34567)).start();
                    serverIsRunning = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("server is already running");
                }
                break;
            case "SHUTDOWN":
                if (serverIsRunning) {
                    pcs.firePropertyChange(userInput, null, "SHUTDOWN");
                    serverIsRunning = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("server is not running");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcl){
    this.pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(pcl);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcl){
    this.pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(pcl);
}
```

}

public class Server implements Runnable, PropertyChangeListener {

```
private int port;
private ServerSocket server;
private String userInput = "";
private Boolean serverIsRunning;

public Server(int port) {
    this.port = port;
    serverIsRunning = true;
}

public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        userInput = evt.getNewValue().toString();
        switch (userInput) {
            case "START":
                System.out.println("Starting server...");
                serverIsRunning = true;
                break;
            case "SHUTDOWN":
                serverIsRunning = false;
                break;
        }
    }


@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) { }

    while (serverIsRunning) {
        try {
            new Thread(new Client(server.accept())).start();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    try {
        server.close();
        System.out.println("shutdown");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "it just wond get out the loop". `while(true)`, what did you expect?

Comment: One of the main purposes of using a listener structure is to be notified of object state change and thus not needing or using a while loop to poll for state change. The proper solution is to **get rid of that while loop**.

Comment: i didnt mean the the one in the main

Comment: i mean the one in the Listenter class

Comment: Exactly what I said -- **get rid of that loop** in the listener class. It serves no useful purpose

Comment: Also you shouldn't be calling any fire methods in the main method.

Comment: i cant get rid of it, i need it for the rest of my project

Comment: ??? No you DON'T need the while loop. And again one of the whole purposes of the listener set up is to avoid just this.

Comment: You're missing @Override annotation on `public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Don't get hung up on bad coding practices, the question is simply regarding why his while loop is not working, yes is poor code but nevertheless the question is not about that

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels  i need a server that will listen all the time for clients to connect

Comment: and i add this @Override annotation but this is not the problem, as i write its work but when its get to the wile loop its wont get out

Comment: I'm not hung up on bad coding practices, but a completely wrong way to use property change listener. Don't misconstrue what I'm suggestion: You need to restructure your entire set up as it is wrong. Period.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you're right, I apologize. @Koby, your while loop will run infinitely because `run()` will be entered once and the condition will always be true. This could work if you added a call to `run()` after `listenToChange = evt.getNewValue().toString();` but as said before is just bad design as you will end up with many threads running an infinite loop, follow the advice on the answer of hovercraft to take full advantage of beans

Answer (score 2):

Again a main purpose of using a listener design pattern is to avoid having to use a while loop to continually poll for state change and instead have the listener and listener support work together to *notify* you when the state of an object changes.

Other issues:

- The Bean should hold the listened-to or "bound" field
- The bean itself should call the `fireXxx` method at the location of change of state, not any of your other classes.
- The listener should not have or need a `while (true)` loop. All it should do is listen and respond to state changes in the Bean, nothing more and nothing less.

For example say your bean looked like this:

```
public class Bean2 {
    // constant for the property change name
    public static final String STATE = "state";
    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs;

    // this is the "bound" field
    private String state = "";

    public Bean2() {
        pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    // notify listeners within the setter
    public void setState(String state) {
        String oldValue = this.state;
        String newValue = state;
        this.state = state;
        pcs.firePropertyChange(STATE, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    // method to remove... 

}
```

Then your listener could be as simple as:

```
public class Listener2 implements PropertyChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("From listener: state change -- new state: " + evt.getNewValue());
        // this code will obviously need to do more...
    }
}
```

and used like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bean2 bean = new Bean2();
    Listener2 listener = new Listener2();
    bean.addPropertyChangeListener(Bean2.STATE, listener);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = "";
    while (!text.equalsIgnoreCase(EXIT)) {
        System.out.print("Enter text or \"EXIT\" to quit: ");
        text = scanner.nextLine();
        if (!text.equalsIgnoreCase(EXIT)) {
            bean.setState(text);
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

See, no while loop, no calling `fireXxx` out of the bean

---

Regarding your edits, I'm still not 100% sure of your entire program set up, but perhaps something along these lines:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyServer2 {
    private static final String EXIT = "exit";
    public static final int PORT = 4444;
    private ServerSocket server;

    public MyServer2() throws IOException {
        server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    }

    public void beanChanged(String text) {
        // *** not sure what you want to do with this text 
        // *** other than to check that it != EXIT
        if (!text.equalsIgnoreCase(EXIT)) {
            try {
                new Thread(new Client(server.accept()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // System.exit(0); // ????
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyServer2 server = null;
        try {
            server = new MyServer2();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bean2 bean = new Bean2();
        Listener2 listener = new Listener2(server);
        bean.addPropertyChangeListener(Bean2.STATE, listener);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = "";
        while (!text.equalsIgnoreCase(EXIT)) {
            System.out.print("Enter text or \"EXIT\" to quit: ");
            text = scanner.nextLine();
            if (!text.equalsIgnoreCase(EXIT)) {
                bean.setState(text);
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

```
public class Bean2 {
    // constant for the property change name
    public static final String STATE = "state";
    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs;

    // this is the "bound" field
    private String state = "";

    public Bean2() {
        pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    // notify listeners within the setter
    public void setState(String state) {
        String oldValue = this.state;
        String newValue = state;
        this.state = state;
        pcs.firePropertyChange(STATE, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    // method to remove...

}
```

```
public class Listener2 implements PropertyChangeListener {
    private MyServer2 myServer2;

    public Listener2(MyServer2 myServer2) {
        this.myServer2 = myServer2;
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        // notify server by calling its public method with new value
        myServer2.beanChanged((String) evt.getNewValue());
    }
}
```

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;

    public Client(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO finish coding

    }

}
```

But this still feels awkward. Note that I usually will put my code to `accept()` a new client in its own thread, since it is blocking code, something like:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        try {
            new Thread(new Client(server.accept()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: ok i read this code but it wont help me if i need to run a server that need to wait for new client          while (!listenToChange.equals("exit") {
            try {
                new Thread(new Client(server.accept());
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }       like this

Comment: Again get rid of the while loop. Instead the code above should be called within `propertyChange` method.

Comment: but i need to run it on diffrent thread so i need to override the run method and put it there, and this is not the problem beacuse that that is on the run method

Comment: @koby: the code above works **for the problem and code you've posted in your question**. If you need it to work in a different situation you need to post an adequate [mcve] that reflects the new situation. We can't help with code not shown.

Comment: i edit the code if you can show me now how can i could rid out of the while loop,thx

Comment: but i need to run listener on diffrent thread(this is the demending of school), and that listener will run the server

Comment: @koby: I can only go by what you've posted in your question, and your comments above suggests that you still need to edit and improve the question, especially the code so that you show a decent [mcve] that represents the problem you're still having. I can stress how important this is.

Comment: ok so i write again the question with all the methods i need,

Comment: the main cannot be change and the class CLI shoud get commads from user and fire change to the server, the server shoud run all the time unit the CLI fired him to shut down(demends from colleage)

Comment: @koby: OK, thank you for the update. Now, how is the current code not working well for you? Note that the while loop that holds the `server.accept()` would be hard to break out of, since I don't know how to unblock the `.accept()` call

Comment: @koby: I also note that your most recent code post is much more consistent with the code that I posted initially, and not with the code that you initially posted in that CLI is your bean and the `fireXxx` method is only called (appropriately so) within the bean, again unlike your original post.

Comment: i dont think that the problem is in the server.accept, because if i replace this all line with empty line its steel wont get out of the loop